# Android - best approach to get thumbnails for recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

In android I am creating an application about gardening.

There will be a **huge list** of plants (1000+) showing with text search on the go - so in Mainactivity will be a button, after clicking on it opens a new Activity with the list of plants. That list is generated as json on my server and via Retrofit I am obtaining it.

I don't want to load that huge list from server after the user clicks the button, as well I don't want multiple request when user searches the plant in the list (and I don't want to store that list in memory as well).

So I had an idea, that all data will be loaded on app start, in MainActivity. `FillData` method will connect to server and fill data to SQLite:

```
if(!prefs.getBoolean("firstTimeRun", false)) {
    FillData(0);
}
else {try (DatabaseHelper myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this)){
    myDb.getWritableDatabase();
    int version = myDb.checkDBversion();
    FillData(version);}
}
```

So now, when user runs the app first time, it will connect to server, get all data and insert to SQLite in the app. As well, if the current version indicator in app DB table is lower than on server, it will fill the db with current data. Otherwise no connection to server is needed.

The data on the server will be from time to time updated, or new plant added (not very often).

This is working very well, user just waits once for loading data on app start, not after each button click and also I am doing text search directly in DB, so no more server requests. So in other Activity I just show the list from DB without any server connection.

The problem is, In recyclerview list of plants, I want to show also images. I wanted to avoid connecting to server while showing the list of plants, but I think it is the only way (e.g. via Picasso), how to show images from the server, as I can't store them into DB in MainActivity as other data.

As well I can't store images in drawable folder that comes with the app, because some images might change or new plants with new images might be added.

Is there a way, how to store images to DB or in the app from the server, so I can update them when DB is updated or add new images when new plant is added to DB?

I think it is also possible to store images into SQLLite database with Base 64 algorithm, but I fear it will then be a huge DB and to convert back the images for each line thousand times via calling complex method is not the best solution...

Comment: most image loading libraries also have caching implementations, have you looked at those ? why wouldn't that work ?

Comment: hm, but not sure if I can rely on cache folder, if they are cached, any new image update won't update the existing image. And then another thing, when pulling data from DB, how to show image from cache that needs to be connected with ID of the DB row. But I will try the caching with Picasso, will see how it works